# Google Analytics crash & exception deobfuscating

Tags: android, exception, google-analytics

I've set up my Google Analytics so i see all the uncaught crashes and exceptions.

I also use proguard to obfuscate. So those reports look like this: `IllegalStateException (@a:a:457) {AsyncTask #2}`

I have some AsyncTasks, but all they are less than 200 lines of code.

I know how to deobfuscate traces that i get in Google Developer Console. I save the trace to a text file and run the retrace.jar using my mapping file via the terminal and see the unobfuscated trace, allowing me to understand where the exception happened.

Tried doing same operation for GA traces and they were not deobfuscated. Is there a way to deobufuscate that trace to understand where the exception happens? I hope there is, because otherwise this function of GA is completely useless.

Comment: please add full error LOG

Comment: Hey, that is the full error log that i specified there. Yes, it consists only from 1 line.

Comment: Google Analytics should let you upload the mapping.txt file like the Google Play Console does (although I haven't had any luck with Google Play deobfuscation even after doing this). I use the line number to go through each of my source files, but many errors refer to files buried among support files which are difficult to access when you don't even know the name of the offending file.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution i've come up with so far is for a trace like `IllegalStateException (@a:a:457) {AsyncTask #2}` to check every activity's line 457 and think wether an IllegalStateException is possible there.